# Can someone help me with reactive sword IK for VR?

Tags: physics, virtual-reality, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, inverse-kinematics

The Goal: To have a sword that collides with the environment, but most importantly, other swords.

the sword is attached to the hand that is driven by the motion controller

The issue: Can't figure out how to calculate hit into wrist/arm IK.(any info on how to do it would be helpful)

Hello here's the rundown. I am trying to make a VR sword mechanic where the sword can interact with terrain and change the hand/arm bone rotations based on the hit. Do not worry about immersion because we plan to do a ghost for when the arm isn't at the same transform as the real arm.

I tried to do a few calculations for sword hit to get the wrist to rotate dependent on how the sword hits a wall/weapon. Also decided I'm not going to do physics for a arm.

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily use the two bone IK node or the older fabrik node in animation bp to change the transform of bones while in animation

Comment: Do you know what would be a good way to calculate my hit into my IK/fabrik node?

Comment: do you mean when the sword hits another sword?? well that has nothing to do with IK , for that the swords collider is enough , although IK can be used to enhance this but im afraid I have never tried it.

On another note keep a vector in the direction of where your sword hits and based upon that you can apply any kind of rotation on your wrist.